# PHP Validation for form

Tags: php, css

I need some help getting my form completed, I want certain input fields to only accept letters, some to accept numbers, etc. Could someone help me with an example so I can learn these?
I want the name to only accept letters, email to accept any but REQUIRE an "@" symbol. Hopefully if I can get help with those, I can do the rest on my own.

Thanks so much

Here is my php form.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Daily Dorm News</title>
</script>
<body>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Your Daily Dorm News Post! </h1>

Welcome <?php if ( isset($_GET['name']) and preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/", $_GET['name']) ) {

    echo $_GET['name'];

} else {

    echo "You entered an invalid name!\n";

}

?><br>


Your email address is: <?php if ( isset($_GET['email']) and preg_match("/.+@.+\..+/i", $_GET['email']) ) {

    echo $_GET['email'];

} else {

    echo "You didn't enter a proper email address!\n";

}
?><br>
You Posted : <?php echo $_GET["message"]; ?><br>
This event happened :<?php echo $_GET["date"]; ?><br>

<?php
// set the default timezone to use. Available since PHP 5.1
date_default_timezone_set('EST');


// Prints something like: Monday 8th of August 2005 03:12:46 PM
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
?>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Daily Dorm News</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>

<body>
<div id="dorm"> <u>Daily Dorm News</u> <br> The best place to get your latest Dorm news </div>
<form action="posting_wall.php" method="get">
<div id="container">
Username:<input type="text" name="name" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{3,15}" title="Letters and numbers only, length 3 to 15" required autofocus><br>
E-mail: <input type="email" name="email"maxlength="20" required><br>
<div class='message'>
Post: <br>
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='message' id='message' pattern=".{3,}" title="3 characters minimum" maxlength="150" required></textarea>
</div>
Date this event took place: <input type="text" name='date' id="datepicker" required> <br>
</div>
<input type="submit">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the `filter_var` function:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

That easily allows you to check a value against a regular expression, validate whether or not it is a float, int, email, url or an ip address.

You can find some examples within PHP documentation:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php

Hope that helps!

Comment: so add those filters just after the "Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"];?><br>" for if I am verifying email for example?

Comment: How can i make my text area require a minimum # of characters, 3, or it wont submit the form? Updated code in op

Comment: Hi!, since PHP is a server-side programming language, you just can't prevent the form to be submited to the server.  You would have to use a client-side programming language such as Javascript.  I recommend that you take a look to jQuery and jQuery validator plugin that allows you to easily check field values before submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option by far is to use PHP's filter_var() function with the second parameter being the FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL type. See: [PHP.net's documentation on it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

Alternatively, if you wanted for some reason to be even more selective than what filter_var() does, you could use regular expressions (abbreviated as regex), which are often used for input validation. PHP.net has good documentation on PHP's preg_match function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Just to provide a quick and rudimentary example:

Your email address is:

```
if ( isset($_GET['email']) and preg_match("/.+@.+\..+/i", $_GET['email']) ) {

    echo $_GET['email'];

} else {

    echo "You didn't enter a proper email address!\n";

}
?>
```

I'm assuming you're not familiar with regex if you posed this question, so I'll explain a little. The regex pattern here (which is the first argument of the preg_match function, and which is enclosed in forward slashes) basically says: accept anything that matches a pattern that has one or more character(s) (represented by .+) followed by the @ symbol followed again by one or more characters followed by a dot (represented by an escaped period, or \.) followed by one or more characters, and make it case-insensitive (represented by the letter i following the closing forward slash of the regex pattern).

Hope that helps!

Comment: so enter that after "Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"];?><br>" or inside there? just confused where to enter the text above.

Comment: If you're referring to the regex example I provided, the code can be left pretty much as is. You said you wanted input validation, so use a conditional if...else statement: if the $_GET['email'] variable is set, AND it matches the regex pattern, then it will run the statement echo $_GET['email']. Otherwise, it returns a message that tells the user he or she didn't enter a proper email address. (Of course, you could do other things in the else clause, like redirect the user back to the form using header() function.) I suggest you try running the code in the browser so you can see how it works.

Comment: @Terry Just to add something: perhaps you are confused (and I'm just guessing  here) because it's a multi-line block of code and you're not sure how it's incorporated in the HTML. The code contained in PHP's opening and closing tags (<?php and ?>) can take up as many or as few lines as you would like in whatever text editor you're using to code your script -- it doesn't matter. It does not need to be contained to a single line. You should be able to just copy and paste the example I provided in between your PHP tags and it will run fine. Just replace echo $_GET["email"]; with my code example.

Comment: yea im confused on where to incorporate it. ok, i copied it into my document, i just uploaded the new code in the OP, can u see if I placed it correctly?

Comment: Ah i think i got it! Thanks, It says if i do thrgkaol.com that I did not enter correct email. Instead of just still taking me to the posting_wall.php page, can I make that it takes me back to the form, however WITHOUT the information I entered deleted? I got it to redirect, but there information is gone when it reloads the form

Comment: Sure. Since you pass the form information through the GET method, I'll stick with that for this example. You just need to add the value that the user entered onto a variable in the URL when you redirect the user back to the form. For example, your `else` clause may say: `header("Location: http://yourdomain.com/yourform.php?useremail=" . $_GET['email']);` ...now, in yourform.php, you can get the value the user typed in by grabbing it from the URL: `<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if (isset($_GET['useremail'])) { echo $_GET['useremail']; }?>">`